# How to have multiple competing consumers for rabbitmq using masstransit

Tags: .net-core, rabbitmq, masstransit

I'm using MassTransit library with RabbitMQ. I'd like to scale out my consumers into different machines however I need to make sure that they're not receiving the same messages. I deployed my consumers in different servers but they're getting same messages. is there a way to fix that?

Comment: As Alexey stated in the answer, when you run multiple instances of the same service, it automatically load balances (via competing consumer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you publish a message, it gets to a message exchange. Each endpoint exchange, which is bound to the message exchange, will get its copy of a message and gets it to the endpoint queue.

In order to implement competing consumers, you have to use the same endpoint name for all the application instances.

It's all available [in the docs](http://masstransit-project.com/troubleshooting/common-gotchas.html#how-do-i-load-balance-consumers-across-machines).